# How to print a message (on shell or http response) to node's user?

Tags: corda

I wrote a flow which can be finished unsuccessfully. So I want to make user know the reason and to show him the message with some description. 
It will be awesome to be able to do this both if node user uses shell or HTTP client.

Can you provide any links to proper papers or guidelines?

UPD

```
package com.template

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import net.corda.core.flows.*
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder
import net.corda.core.utilities.unwrap

// *********
// * Flows *
// *********
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class SandboxSellerFlow(val iouValue: Int,
              val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    /** The progress tracker provides checkpoints indicating the progress of the flow to observers. */
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    /** The flow logic is encapsulated within the call() method. */
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // We retrieve the notary identity from the network map.
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val flowSession = initiateFlow(otherParty)

        // We create the transaction components.
        val outputState = IOUState(iouValue, ourIdentity)

        val packet = flowSession.sendAndReceive<Boolean>(iouValue)
        val res = packet.unwrap{data->data}

        if(res)
            throw FlowException("I've been rejected")

        val command = Command(TemplateContract.Commands.Action(), ourIdentity.owningKey)

        // We create a transaction builder and add the components.
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
                .addOutputState(outputState, TemplateContract.ID)
                .addCommand(command)

        // We sign the transaction.
        val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // We finalise the transaction.
        subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx))
    }
}

@StartableByRPC
@InitiatedBy(SandboxSellerFlow::class)
class SandboxBuyerFlow(internal val sellerSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(){
        // Wait for a trade request to come in from the other party.
        val any = sellerSession.receive<Any>().unwrap{data->data}
        if(any is Int) {
            if (any > 10)
                sellerSession.send(false)
            else
                sellerSession.send(true)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should throw an exception in the flow with an appropriate error message. This error will be automatically shown in the node shell when the flow fails. If using an HTTP client, you'll need to catch the exception and display an error message to the user.

For example, suppose I have the flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        throw FlowException("This flow always throws an exception.")
    }
}
```

If I run this flow from the shell, I get the following exception:

```
Tue Jan 29 12:46:21 GMT 2019>>> start Initiator


   Done
☠   This flow always throws an exception.
```

Comment: Hm, I have ```if (res) throw FlowException("I've been rejected") ``` lines, but there is nothing displayed on shell.

Comment: Hm. Very strange, my exception throwing doesn't print any messages. Can you imagine why? I'll add my source code.